# Norwegian Logitech K750 keyboard for Mac, used through VMware Fusion with a Bootcamp virtual machine, incorrect keyboard layout

Tags: macos, keyboard-layout, vmware-fusion, logitech-keyboard

The title really sums it up, but here is the problem:

- I recently bought the [Logitech K750 keyboard for Mac](http://www.logitech.com/no-no/product/wireless-solar-keyboard-k750-mac)
- The keyboard has a Norwegian layout, like the lower keyboard [here](http://img.gfx.no/1071/1071792/key3.jpg).
- On the Mac, hitting the key right next to the left Shift key, labelled "<" and ">", gives me the correct keys, in any software (that I've tried)
- When using VMware Fusion, to boot my Windows 7 Bootcamp partition as a virtual machine, hitting that key either gives me "|" or "§" depending on whether I hold Shift down or not, clearly the wrong key
- Hitting the key to the left of the 1 on the main keyboard, through VMware Fusion, gives me "<" and ">"

It seems the key to the left of 1 and to the left of the left Shift key has switched places.

I have not gone through all the keys to see if there are any other details wrong. I'm a programmer, so displacing < and > is a big problem, so I stopped there.

Is there anything I can change configuration-wise to fix this?

I have installed [Logitech K750 Control Center](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/support/wireless-solar-keyboard-k750-mac?section=downloads&bit=64&osid=21) on the Mac, but I have not done anything in Windows. Since the K750 keyboard *for Mac* doesn't seem to come with Windows drivers, I'm not entirely sure what to change or install here.

Comment: Can you [change to a Mac keyboard layout in Windows](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1005578)?

Comment: I can change to a "apple" layout in Windows, doesn't change anything related to this though.

Comment: Does it work normally with other keyboards or other ISO keyboards? If the only difference is that those two keys are flipped, you can remap them in the Keyboard & Mouse tab of VMware Fusion's preferences.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the available layouts in the Windows VM map your keyboard correctly, there is always the [Microsoft Keybord Layout Creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx). You can load a Norwegian layout as a template (File-> Load Existing) and switch the positions of the misbehaving keys. When done, rename the layout (Project-> Properties) and build an installer.